# ORA-01861: literal does not match format string error in PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an query in PL/SQL which have some filters and after that gives me some id numbers.
While I am executing my query I am getting this error:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Note: If I execute my query without last AND statement it works. So I think that it is about DATE and some date parameters but I couldnt solve my issue. I am open to suggestion and solution advices. Thank you from now.

```
SELECT DISTINCT intl_prod_id
  FROM apld_bill_rt abr,
       acct_bill ab
  WHERE     abr.cdate > SYSDATE - 1000
      AND abr.CHRG_TP = 'INSTALLMENT'
      AND abr.TAX_CATG_ID = 'NOTAX'
      AND abr.acct_bill_id = ab.acct_bill_id
      AND ab.bill_date = (to_date('01/011/2011','DD/MM/YYYY'));
```

Morever, this is a example of the ab.bill_date
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
to_date('01/011/2011','DD/MM/YYYY')
            ---
         there's no 011 month (as far as I can tell)
```

Comment: Looks like it is about my typo mistake, thank you. Sometimes my brain burns because of overworking haha.

Comment: Slow down, at least a little bit :)